# Why is Bugzilla missing from 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, bugzilla

Why has the bugzilla package been removed from the Ubuntu 12.04 repository?

Is there any PPA to make it work and update automatically or do I need to download from bugzilla website and backup/compile/install/restore every time?

I couldn't find any information on the internet, but some guys having the same issue and no one answering them.

Answer (score 4):

Bugzilla was removed from Debian because no one was maintaining it.

- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=638705

As a result of this it's not available in Ubuntu either. Usually if something is unmaintained for a long time it's not available unless someone from the community is willing to do the work to maintain it, which is unfortunately not the case here.